# External jar/library launch4j problems

Tags: java, jar, jsoup, external, launch4j

I'm currently working on a program that uses an external library called `jsoup-1.10.1`. I've used `launch4j` before I started using the `jsoup` jar but now that I have to use this library I can't figure out how to combine `jsoup` with my project so that I can generate an exe that works properly. I've done some research on the matter but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Create a single jar with `onejar`
and then use this jar in `launch4j`.

Works well with many external jars. Only loading resources can be a bit tricky, but is possible.

example part in `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.xy.Mainclass</mainClass>
                        <attachToBuild>false</attachToBuild>
                        <classifier>onejar</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>console</headerType>
                        <jar>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.one-jar.jar</jar>
                        <outfile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.exe</outfile>
                        <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot</mainClass>
                            <preCp>anything</preCp>
                        </classPath>

                        <singleInstance>
                            <mutexName>${project.artifactId}</mutexName>
                        </singleInstance>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
                            <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                            <initialHeapSize>128</initialHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                            <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                            <copyright>...</copyright>
                            <productVersion>0.0.0.1</productVersion>
                            <txtProductVersion>0.0.0.1</txtProductVersion>
                            <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                            <companyName>...</companyName>
                            <internalName>${project.artifactId}</internalName>
                            <originalFilename>${project.artifactId}.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-exe</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.exe</file>
                                <type>exe</type>
                                <classifier>executable</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but from what I dug up on their website it only seems to work with Eclipse projects. I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: this solution works with any `maven` project. What do you use for building your application? `ant` which mean you have an `build.xml`? Maybe you could add some more datails to your question...

Comment: you can use `onejar` with `ant` as well: [link](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=ant)